# Asp.Net MVC 4 Footable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, footable

I have an asp.net mvc 4 project. I need to use Footable plugin(http://fooplugins.com/plugins/footable-jquery/) as data table in my project. How can I set footable data source from controller? Is there any tutorial for usage footable in asp.net mvc platform?

Comment: FooTable is a jQuery plugin, which means it's only Html and JavaScript, so it has nothing to do with Asp.Net. You need to output a `View` with the respective Html.

Comment: Why do you want to use Footable?  What feature do you want?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to do webforms in MVC, but they are different.

1. Read the [following documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/displaying-a-table-of-database-data-cs) on how to create tables using MVC. Not the best docs, but should get you started on creating tables.
2. After you created the table read the FooTable docs.